# Can we use NDK to transmit WiFi probe request packets with a specified SSID?

Tags: android, android-ndk, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I was trying to test if we can create an app to transmit probe request packets with SSID as a variable parameter. I have tried with the Java API by saving a network configuration and then initiating a scan, but this works only if I restart the app after a change in the network configuration SSID. Is there a way to do the same without requiring an app restart, maybe through NDK?

Answer (score 0):

There's a port of aircrack-ng to Android. It requires rooting and works only on some devices. It switches the wifi to monitor mode and then it is possible to send whatever packet you want. (On most modern devices the monitor mode is not allowed.)

Unfortunately, if you code for portability, this is no solution.